# send location KeyboardButton does not send any data in php-telegram-bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm using https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/ php library to make a telegram Bot.

To get location of user I wrote these Command:

```
public function execute ()
    {
        $data['chat_id'] = $this->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();

        $data['reply_markup'] = (new Keyboard(
            (new KeyboardButton('Send Location'))->setRequestLocation(true)
        ))
            ->setOneTimeKeyboard(true)
            ->setResizeKeyboard(true)
            ->setSelective(true);


        $data['text'] = 'To send your location , touch below Button';

        return Request::sendMessage($data);
    }
```

"Send Location" Button shown But when User touch it, no things sent to program at all. this is while I'm using mobile device(no desktop Telegram ) and my location access.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on GPS navigation on your device. If it's turned on, check permissions for your Telegram client.